# How many preemptively built circuits?

Tags: circuit

I want to know how many preemptively circuits Tor can builds. I got confused about it when I read "[Tor Path Specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git?a=blob_plain;hb=HEAD;f=path-spec.txt)".

According to this article, at the startup Tor builds 3 clean circuits, but somewhere else it says Tor builds 2 circuits for each recently seen ports (If there are 12 or more clean circuits open, it doesn't open more even if it has more predictions.)

*What does Tor actually do when preemptively building circuits?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's complicated.  There are many reasons Tor builds circuits preemtively: access hidden services, provide them, exit to any ports that you may want to use (based on recent behavior) and also measuring the network to determine what latency/circuit build times to expect.

[`circuit_predict_and_launch_new()`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/tor-0.2.4.20:/src/or/circuituse.c#l857) has all the gory details.